# Angular 6 : Print to HTTP printer from HTTPS

Tags: angular, zpl

I have an Angular 6 application running behind Nginx with HTTPS.

I want to send commands to my ZPL printer to print labels but the printer accepts only HTTP protocol. Browser won't let me run HTTP stating CORS issues.

What could be the possible solution for this?

Disabling CORS on browser is not a solution

Answer (score 1):

The most straightforward solution would be to configure nginx as a reverse proxy to the zebra printer.  That keeps your browser request in the same domain.

https://linuxize.com/post/nginx-reverse-proxy/

Answer (score -2):

You can convert your app in electron-angular app if the client is in the same network.